# what is the relation of VGS on P and N channel mosfet

Tags: mosfet, switches, power-electronics

I'm a little bit confused on the Vgs(voltage-gate-source) of a mosfet...from what i understand so far the Vgs is simply the potential difference of the voltage applied from gate to source...

FOR EXAMPLE:
using a p-channel mosfet
assume that Vg=10 volts and my Vs=18 volts
so i get a VGS= -8

using a n-channel mosfet
assume that Vg=10 volts and my 
Vs=0 (vs is always 0 since the source is at the ground level)
so i get a VGS= 10

i hope someone will clear this confusion of mine...TIA

Comment: What is your confusion?

Comment: im confused if all the things i said was right i dont know if those are right

Comment: im sorry im just new to this electronics stuff

Comment: Yes you are correct. Vgs = Vg-Vs. For both n and p channel MOSFETs.

Comment: Yes you are correct. N channel FETs are usually easier to understand, I still have to stop and think about the polarity of P channel FETs too. Sometimes the negative sign is omitted in P channels, and simply written as the absolute value, |Vgs| = 8 V. However, in this case you do have to double check that the gate is indeed negative when compared to the source.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't really ask a question but I can state that what you said all sounds correct except that N-channel mosfets do not have to have the source attached to ground. Often times they will be used as a high side switch with some kind of driving/bootstrap circuit to elevate the gate over whatever drain voltage is being controlled.

Comment: i didn't know that we can use n channel mosfet for high side switching

Comment: Yes they can, a bootstrap is a fancy way of saying a capacitor that is charged to a high voltage. If you are trying to switch a high side FET on a 20 V rail with a 3.3 V controller, a capacitor is charged to 20 V with a charge pump to turn on the gate.

Comment: thanks for confirming the things i said...and i know now why i wreck my p channel mosfet because i exceeded the maximum vgs rated for that mosfet which is +/- 20 volts.....because i applied a VG=10 and VS=35 and their difference is high that i reach a VGS=-25

Comment: Place a zener diode that clamps below your max Vgs across the gate to source connection and limit the current through the zener with a resistor. Some FETs have this zener built into the package. Here is an example of controlling a high side load with GPIO. https://acroname.com/sites/default/files/u9/electronicloads_02.jpg

Comment: @electronicnoob - " i know now why i wreck my p channel mosfet because i exceeded the maximum vgs rated for that mosfet which is +/- 20 volts". Yup. And you won't forget it easily, and you'll have a better idea that reading the data sheet carefully is a good idea. Welcome to real-world engineering. While paying attention to theory is a really good idea, a certain amount of hands-on experience (and embarrassing failure) is part of the game. "Good judgement comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgment."